Duplicating and routing packets with iptables
Forgive me. I am inexperienced with CLI networking tools.
I have 3 Linux machines (a client (C), server (S), and a node in the middle (M)). C and M have a direct link on subnet 192.168.100.0/24. For simplicity, I'll call the interfaces and IP addresses they're connected through C_M (C's interface to M) and M_C (M's interface to C). C and M are each connected to S through separate interfaces (M_S, C_S) on subnet 10.45.0.0/24. S uses the same interface (S_CM) to connect to both. S is a couple hops away from both C and M.
My goal is to send packets between C and S using both paths simultaneously (client-server, client-middle-server). The same packets (duplicates) should be sent along each path. C simultaneously sends duplicate packets destined for S via its link to S and its link to M. S does the same thing back. M just forwards the packets it receives. I am trying to do this with iptables and static ip routes.
However, the paths using M don't work. To test if this configuration was working, I sent two pings from the server to the client and the client to the server. I used iptables matching rules to count the incoming and outgoing packets for each node. Based on the results, I came to these conclusions:
M sees the traffic from C but doesn't forward it.
M doesn't receive anything from S.
C receives the duplicate packets from S but only through C_S.
S does not receive the duplicate packets from C.
C is correctly sending the duplicate packets via both interfaces.
My settings are as follows. The default setting for all iptables in each node is ACCEPT. Each node already knows to send 10.45.0.0/24 and 192.168.100.0/24 traffic to its interface in that same subnet.

Client: iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -d S_CM -j TEE --gateway M_C
Middle: ip r add C_S via I_C
Server: sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -d C_S -j TEE --gateway M_S

I never change the source or destination address of any packet.
My theory is that I'm misunderstanding TEE. Maybe M has to do something special to be able to forward C's packets? I'm very certain now that TEE's gateway can't be more than one hop away (which would explain why M isn't receiving anything from S).
However, I'm not sure how to fix this. Any advice is appreciated.
